# Discrepancy Between Saved and Emailed Reports

Tags: jasperserver

Jasper n00b here...

We've got some reports that run weekly. They both save a copy of the report to a specified folder in the repository, as well as email a copy of the report to specified users.

We're finding that at times, there are discrepancies between these two reports. Obviously, there should not be. Same report. Same input params. Same scheduled job.

Not something that I can easily reproduce, as it's intermittent (as with all fun troubleshooting tasks). And lacking familiarity with Jasper in general, not even sure where to begin looking.

I apologize in advance for the vague/general question, but if anybody has any insights into where I might even begin to start looking, it'd be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT TO ADD:** We've had a couple of occasions now where the emailed version of the report is blank, but the saved version in the repository is fine. Thoughts??

Comment: You can check the input parameters, timezone settings, executed queries (if you have), exporters settings

Comment: Hi Alex... thanks for the reply. I don't believe it's any of the input params. This is a single scheduled task for a single report. But at times, the version of the report that gets emailed has a different number of rows to the report that got saved to the repository.

Comment: What datasource are you using for your JasperReports? I suspect that there are chances that the datasource your are using is behaving differently in different situations. For example, if the datasource is returning a bit different on different timings. Also have you enabled the log on the Jasper Server side if there are some errors?

Comment: Datasource is Amazon Redshift. As far as behaving differently in different situations, there should be no different situations. This is a report is scheduled to run, it runs, it emails the report and saves the report. Those two copies of the report should be identical. However, they are sometimes different.